# ubuntu 18.04 resolution issue

Tags: lubuntu

I am using lenovo ideapad z470.
Here is the spec if it helps 
https://www.cnet.com/products/lenovo-ideapad-z470/specs/

During ubuntu installation I had to give 'nomodeset' to boot in, but now I am having issue with resolution, it is stuck on 1024 X 768.

[image]

[image: also my laptop say it has nvidia geoforce, but I don't see it here, probably it is something to do nomodeset]

also my laptop say it has nvidia geoforce, but I don't see it here, probably it is something to do nomodeset
When I remove nodemodeset during boot ubuntu doesn't even come to login screen.

Answer (score 0):

My laptop's inbuilt graphics card was incompatible to run 16.04, going back to 14.04.
Windows 10 runs smoother though, but it lacks the performance ubuntu gives.